# Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, linq, icollection

Getting error while executing below code, new to LINQ and not able to find how to assign child object "StudentAddresses" values which getting as icollection type in to students model

```
IList<StudentViewmodel> students = null;

using (var CTX = new StudentEntities())
{
    students = CTX.Students.Include("JP").Select(
        s => new StudentViewmodel()
        {
            Id = s.StudentId,
            FirstName = s.FirstName,
            LastName = s.LastName,
            address =  new AddressViewmodel()
            {
                // Address1 = s.StudentAddresses.Select(t => t.Address1).ToString()
                Address1 = s.StudentAddresses.OfType<AddressViewmodel>().FirstOrDefault().Address1.ToString()
            }
        }

        ).ToList<StudentViewmodel>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved , here is updated code

```
        IList<StudentViewmodel> students = null;using (var CTX = new StudentEntities())
        {
            students = CTX.Students.Include("JP").Select(
                s => new StudentViewmodel()
                {
                    Id = s.StudentId,
                    FirstName = s.FirstName,
                    LastName = s.LastName,
                    address = new AddressViewmodel()
                    {
                       Address1 = s.StudentAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Address1 ,
                       Address2 = s.StudentAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Address2,
                       City = s.StudentAddresses.FirstOrDefault().City,
                       State = s.StudentAddresses.FirstOrDefault().State
                    }
                }

                ).ToList<StudentViewmodel>();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help you

```
IList<StudentViewmodel> students = null;

using (var CTX = new StudentEntities())
{
    students = CTX.Students.Include("JP").ToList().Select(
        s => new StudentViewmodel()
        {
            Id = s.StudentId,
            FirstName = s.FirstName,
            LastName = s.LastName,
            address =  new AddressViewmodel()
            {
                // Address1 = s.StudentAddresses.ToList().Select(t => t.Address1).ToString()
                Address1 = s.StudentAddresses.OfType<AddressViewmodel>().FirstOrDefault().Address1.ToString()
            }
        }

        ).ToList<StudentViewmodel>();
}
```

if there is a problem for comment access property and test it again.and be sure where do you have a problem.Thanks

Comment: comment address property and run it again.if there is a problem.send a message again.I change the answer.